# How to get around the "xs:group cannot be placed inside xs:all" limitation?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

Is there any reason why `<xs:group>` cannot appear inside `<xs:all>`, but only inside `<xs:sequence>`?

Let's see an example. Say, there is a list of tags (`<a>` to `<d>` and `<e>` to `<f>` - see example below) which do not appear in any particular order, but always wrapped into another object (either `<foo>` or `<bar>`); `<foo>`={`<a>`, `<b>`, `<c>`, `<d>`}; `<bar>`={`<e>`, `<b>`, `<c>`, `<f>`}:

```
<foo>
  <a>a1</a>
  <b>b1</b>
  <c>c1</c>
  <d>d1</d>
</foo>

<foo>
  <d>d2</d>
  <b>b2</b>
  <c>c2</c>
  <a>a2</a>
</foo>

<bar>
  <e>e3</e>
  <b>b3</b>
  <c>c3</c>
  <f>f3</f>
</bar>
```

I want to extract tags `<b>` and `<c>` into `xs:group` and use `<xs:group ref="...">` when defining *complexType* of `<foo>` and `<bar>` in the XSD. However, due to the restriction mentioned above, this is not possible.

What would you suggest as a workaround for the given problem? Chances are, I am doing something stupid, but again why is this incorrect?

Comment: Now you know why I hate the w3c.

Comment: Such a simple requirement is not provided in w3c?? Bad!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deterministic content rule is the reason for the restriction. If you want a full understanding, read van der Vlist's book or [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why this limitation exists, although I can see that the possible combinations of a fully-featured `<group>` (with nested `<choice>` and `<all>`) inside another `<all>` might be a bit confusing to the developer (well, me anyway) and especially to users.

As a workaround I'll suggest what you've probably already come up with: that is, to declare another `<complexType>` for `<b>` and `<c>` and to use *that* inside your `<foo>` and `<bar>`:

```
  <xs:complexType name="bcType">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="bc" type="bcType" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="bar">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="f" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="bc" type="bcType" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I would definitely use this approach, however then I would have to rename "b" and "c" elements into "bc" which is not an appropriate solution due to legacy reasons. I need to name them "b" and "c" and that's why I use xs:group.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to forego using <group> -- unfortunately!